# Embedded Java key-value storage

Tags: java, nosql, key-value-store

I'm looking for a persistent key-value storage to use in my application. Specifically:

1. It must be embeddable into Java application. Pure Java solution would be the best.
2. Data must be persisted on disk, in-memory-only storage is not an option. Memory footprint size is important and overall size of key-value map can be quite large. Ideally I'd like to have some kind of LRU cache implemented over the storage.
3. Both keys & values are strings (don't need to support Java object serialization, etc).
4. Concurrent reads/writes are important.

What would be the best option in such case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [key-value store suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639080/key-value-store-suggestion)

Comment: There is another way if it helps, use TayzGrid as a [java key value store](http://blogs.tayzgrid.com/using-an-in-memory-key-value-store-to-scale-java-apps/) and dump the cache data periodically

Answer (score 5):

[OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.org/) ([SO info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/orient-db/info)) seems to fit the bill.

The documentation is occasionally a bit lacking, but I belive it fulfills the criteria you are listing.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know it is best or not but [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) has these options. You can store your data on memory with a backup on disk. There is an [example](http://hazelcast.com/docs/2.0/manual/multi_html/ch02s03.html) on hazelcast.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Voldemort](http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/) when we had to replace normal HashMap when large data had to be supported. Performance was really great.

> value = store.get(key)
>
> store.put(key, value)
>
> store.delete(key)

In next oppurtunity to try a key-value store, I will in all probability try out [Redis](http://redis.io/)

Answer (score 2):

I would use SQLite ([SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)). It is a relational-database like file storage, that will allow you to store key-values and any other thing you may need. It has a very low footprint and is quite fast.

It is very commonly used on Android applications for all these reasons.